# Can I use general relativity to get EM radiation emitted by accelerating charged particle?

Tags: electromagnetism, general-relativity, classical-mechanics

I know from special relativity that an costant velocity charged particle generates a magnetic field (from a frame that is still), can I use GR to derive EM generated by an AC current?

Comment: GR is a theory of gravity. An AC current doesn't need a gravitational field to exist. So, it is possible to have EM radiation in situations where GR is not necessary.

Comment: Okay, but can I use GR to have the analytical EM wave generated by an accelerated charged particle (could be AC, but a single particle should be easier). With special relativity you can derive the magnetic field observed from an external frame of a particle moving at costant veloity. pProblem is that my particle accelerates, therefore I cannot use special rleativity but rather general, but I was asking if this is actually possible.

Comment: You can also use SR for accelerated particles observed from an inertial frame. And even for accelerated frames (see Rindler coordinates). GR is only necessary when the space-time is not flat.

Comment: thank you, I'll look into the topic